# How can I render multiple conditions in ternary operator in React native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Among the things that satisfy the condition of item.diaryClass.name === "pack" in reactnative
If item.diaryId === 778, I want to render chicken, if 776 renders buger, and if 775 renders pizza.
However, when I run my code, only the chiken value is displayed and 776 and 775 are nulled. How do I fix my code?

this is my code

```
return (

{item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 778 ?  
(<Text>
    chicken
</Text>)
:
(null)

}


{item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 776 ?  
(<Text>
    buger
</Text>)
:
(null)
}


{item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 775 ?  
(<Text>
    pizza
</Text>)
:
(null)

}

)
```

Comment: What result are you expecting? Explain more in detail.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```js
    return (
    <View>
    {item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 778 ?  
    (<Text>
        chicken
    </Text>)
    :
    (null)
    
    }
    
    
    {item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 776 ?  
    (<Text>
        buger
    </Text>)
    :
    (null)
    }
    
    
    {item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 775 ?  
    (<Text>
        pizza
    </Text>)
    :
    (null)
    
    }
    </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```js
return (

{item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 778 ?  
(<Text>
    chicken
</Text>)
:
item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 776 ?  
(<Text>
    buger
</Text>)
:
item.diaryClass.name === "pack" && item.diaryId === 775 ?  
(<Text>
    pizza
</Text>)
:
(null)
}
```